# simple c++ binary file reading

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have a binary file created by some fortran code. I want to write a c++ code to read this binary file and then spit it out through std::cout. Here is so far my code:

```
    #include<fstream>
    #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  ifstream file("tofu.txt", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::ate);
  ifstream::pos_type size;
  if(file.is_open()){
    size = file.tellg();
    cout << "size = " << size << '\n';
    file.seekg(0);
    char bar[500];
    file.read((char*) (&bar), size);
    file.close();
    string foo(bar);
    cout << "foo = " << foo << '\n';
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  return 0;
}
```

However, when compiled and run, the code gives me nothing:

```
size = 250
foo =
```

Could someone tell me where I'm doing wrong in the code? Thanks!

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour because the contents of `bar` don't form a null-terminated string.

Comment: What does the file contain? If the first byte is zero, for example, it works just fine.

Comment: @KerrekSB: good catch. `char bar[500];` should be replaced with `char bar[500] = {0};`

Comment: With the right null termination, your program [works as excepted](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cEeBkuzYOq0Va36x).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to terminate your char array, leading to undefined behaviour. Fix it like this:

```
char bar[500];
assert(size < 500);
file.read((char*) (&bar), size - 1);
bar[size] = '\0';
```

(Make sure you check that `size` isn't larger than you have space for, too!)